# Migration from Salesforce IQ to salesforce Sales Cloud

Tags: migration, salesforceiq

We have a salesforce IQ org with Accounts, contacts and related activities...Now we want to migrate to Salesforce sales Cloud. Currently we have created a trial salesforce org and want to test our functionality there.

I am going to follow these steps for migration : https://help.salesforceiq.com/articles/use-the-migration-tool

So my doubts are,  1)Can i migrate my salesforce IQ to TRIAL version?  2) When i complete the migration using these steps, does that mean old salesforce org will be modified in any way?

The reason i am asking these questions is first i want to migrate my salesforce IQ org to trial version and test there. But i want to keep using Salesforce IQ org for while i am doing testing in trial org.

This is first time i am doing migration...Anything critical, i am supposed to know before migration.

Thanks for your Time!

Comment: 1) You can migrate to Trial version , but it will have limitation on storage.2)  Nothing will be changed in old sf org since you are only reading from it .